# ZF2 Default Routing Configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework2, workflow

I am having trouble with the workflow when creating new modules/controllers to the ZF2 Skeleton Application.

I created a new module test and navigated to mydomain/test.  This returns a 404 error until I do the following:

1. Define my Module in the global config file
2. Define my route in my module config file
3. Define my Controller as an invokables in the module config file
4. Define the path of my view as a view_manager in the module Config file

I am new to ZF2 and trying to better understand the workflow for Application development.  This seems like a very cumbersome way to develop, as there is so much configuration needed.

(Rapid application Development??)

Is there a Default means of defining literal routes, controllers, and view rendering in ZF2?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your module with zftool, it will add it to your global config.
2. You will have to create at least one route for each module, take a look at the route in the Application module with this route you're covering allot the comment says:

   > The following is a route to simplify getting started creating new
   >   controllers and actions without needing to create a new module. Simply
   >   drop new controllers in, and you can access them using the path
   >   /application/:controller/:action
3. You will have to add controller to the invokables
4. Use template_path_stack:

   ```
   'view_manager' => array(
       'template_path_stack' => array(
           __DIR__ . '/../view',
       ),
   )
   ```

   i use template_path_stack during development and template_map in production

Comment: Thanks this should make things easier!!

I have been using the ZF tool, and looking at contributions on github where controllers are added to invokeables: https://github.com/RalfEggert/FrilleZFTool/commit/1b741ca0796259c3ddad182dbf3b398d9eae2410

template_path_stack will find all views corresponding to the controller via Controller name?  I was using template_map like a dummy!

Comment: template_path_stack gets your view based on controller & action name, template_map is alot faster i feel (didn't really test it just my experience but its obvious). Extending ZF tool functionality would be a great way to improve your workflow!